# Setting end-of-line character for puts

Tags: ruby

I have an array of entries I would like to print.

Being *arr* the array, I used just to write:

```
puts arr
```

Then I needed to use the DOS format end-of-line: \r\n, so I wrote:

```
arr.each { |e| print "#{e}\r\n" }
```

This works correctly, but I would like to know if there is a way to specify what end-of-line format to use so that I could write something like:

```
$eol = "\r\n"
puts arr
```

**UPDATE 1**

I know that *puts* will use the correct line-endings depending on the platform it is run on, but I need this because I will write the output to a file.

**UPDATE 2**
As Mark suggested, setting *$\* is useful. Anyway it just works for *print*.
For example,

```
irb(main):001:0> a = [1, 2, 3]
=> [1, 2, 3]
irb(main):002:0> $\ = "\r\n"
=> "\r\n"
irb(main):003:0> print a
123
=> nil
irb(main):004:0> puts a
1
2
3
=> nil
```

*print* prints all array items on a single line and then add *$\*, while I would like the behaviour of puts: adding *$\* after each item of the array.
Is this possible at all without using Array#each?

Comment: Doesn't puts add a carriage return depending on the platform ? Could you tell us what output you get and what output you want ?

Comment: @philippe: Yes I know but I will write the output to a text file that I want to be stored with CR/LF line endings

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Ruby variable `$\` will set the record separator for calls to print and write:

```
>> $\ = '!!!'
=> "!!!"
>> print 'hi'
hi!!!=> nil
```

Alternatively you can refer to `$\` as `$OUTPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR` if you import the [English](http://stdlib.rubyonrails.org/libdoc/English/rdoc/index.html) module.

---

`Kernel#puts` is equivalent to `STDOUT.puts`; and `IO.puts` "writes a newline after every element that does not already end with a newline sequence".  So you're out of luck with pure `puts` for arrays.  However, the `$,` variable is the separator string output between parameters suck as `Kernel#print` and `Array#join`.   So if you can handle calling `print arr.join`, this might be the best solution for what you're doing:

```
>> [1,2,3].join
=> "123"
>> $, = '---'
=> "---"
>> [1,2,3].join
=> "1---2---3"
>> $\ = '!!!'
=> "!!!"
>> print [1,2,3].join
1---2---3!!!=> nil
```

Comment: Nice, but is it possible to do the same with puts?
I ask this because doing --

    $\ = "\r\n" ;
    print arr --

prints the array items on a single line while I would like to automatically print each entry on a different line, like *puts* does