# Ruby Write txt file DOS/Windows

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, text-files

Maybe this is a beginner question, but I could not find the problem yet.
I need to write a text file with Ruby.
I can write and create the file to export, but the time I export the file and it is read in other software, it tells me it is a UNIX file and the program requires it to be DOS / Windows.

How can I do this with Ruby?
I use Rails 4 in the project.

Example of how I am writing.

```
File.open(filePath, "w+"){ |file| file.write("blablabla\n")}
```

Comment: Do you mean [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2856038/setting-end-of-line-character-for-puts)?

Comment: @tadman, thanks man, I add '\r\n' and now the file is a DOS format for the software. How I supposed before, this is a beginner question. I really thankful for you help! If you want, make a answer in this question with this solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\r\n` instead:

```
File.open(filePath, "w+"){ |file| file.write("blablabla\r\n")}
```

- Using `\n (0x0a)` only is 'unix style'.
- Using `\r\n (0x0d 0x0a)` is 'windows style'.

Although most software should be able to handle both.

Comment: A lot of DOS-origin Windows software has no idea that LF encoding is a thing.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't very clearly documented but `File.open` also accepts these `String#encode` options:

```
File.open('a.txt', 'w+', crlf_newline: true){ |file| file.write("blablabla\n")}
```

and

```
File.open('a.txt', 'w+', newline: :crlf){ |file| file.write("blablabla\n")}
```

Either will force Ruby to write CRLF instead of LF (CR is `\r` and LF is `\n`).